# Problem with multiple includes in VSCode / platformio

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, platformio

The issue occurs when I try to work with multiple files in VS Code / PlatformIO.

So I built an example to show the problem:

The linker (firmware.elf) says: *'multiple definition of 'variable';'*

**var.h:**

```
#ifndef var_h
#define var_h

#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>

int variable;

void set_var(int number);

#endif // var_h
```

**var.cpp**

```
#include "var.h"

void set_var(int number){
    variable = number;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "var.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(variable);
  delay(2000);
}
```

**platformio.ini**

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
```

I've already tried using either `#pragma once` or `#ifndef ...` exclusively, but it didn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how header guards (your `#ifndef var_h` and associated directives) work and also how *declarations* of 'external' variables work.

The header guards (either the aforementioned or the `#pragma once` directive) will prevent multiple inclusion/processing of that file from any given, *single* translation unit (TU) but not from different TUs. So, for example, if one source file has multiple `#include "var.h"` lines – or if it also includes another header which itself has a `#include "var.h"` line – then those guards will prevent multiple inclusions. However, when you compile "var.cpp" and "main.cpp" (separately), the 'context' is reset for each one. Thus, each of those compilations will see the `int variable;` line, so causing multiple definitions.

In your case, what you need to do is specify *in the header* that `variable` is an `int` but is **defined** elsewhere: `extern int variable;`. Then, in **only one** source file (most likely "var.cpp") provide the actual definition, with a line like `int variable;` (preferably, with an initial value, though: `int variable = 0;`).